# Why does open scene graph only render if UseVertexBufferObject is enabled?

Tags: opengl, glsl, openscenegraph, displaylist, vertex-buffer-objects

I have written a program with OpenSceneGraph (interfaced into Qt Gui) at work and all was fine. Now that I took the program home (i.e. I got the source code home and compiled it at home), I don't see the scene anymore unless I set the option `setUseVertexBufferObjects(true)` which leads me to believe that the scene just doesn't render objects that aren't set up like this (i.e. the objects aren't just culled). The models are definitely a child of the viewer camera when rendering and I don't use any node masks that would lead to culling either. I reset the position of at least one object to be in the view of the camera, so it should not be a frustum culling.

My shaders use `#version330`, my graphics card at work is a NVidia Quadro 4000 (I believe), my graphics card at home is a Radeon HD 5870 so the hardware should not be a problem.

The OpenSceneGraph installation is a fresh one, so obviously I might have done a mistake here, but I wouldn't know which setting would lead to this "behaviour".

So, why might this happen?

Comment: you probably created an OpenGL core profile

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be that. CodeXL tells me the following about the GLContext

`Renderer Version
4.5.13399 Compatibility Profile/Debug Context 15.201.1151.1008`